# How to replace nan values in read_csv?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading a flat file with `read_csv` and flat file as some NaN values because of which it is changing the datatype to float instead of integer which I dont want.

Is there any way to replace the NaN values with 0 in the `read_csv` method?

I know I can do `df.fillna(value=0)` but my question is how can I replace these nan values in the `read_csv`.

```
decop=pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\mnk044\\Downloads\\amna_decp_part-m-00000", sep="\x01", names=clist)
```

Comment: Why not just add an extra line of code to replace the `NaN` and convert to int? I don't think it can be done explicitely in the `read_csv` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Filling NaN values while loading data is currently not supported (see the [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) docs for information on all the supported functionality).

Your only option is to first read, and then call `fillna`.

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Next, if you want to convert your float columns to integers, then filter on `df.dtypes`.

```
c = df.columns[df.dtypes == float]
df[c] = df[c].astype(int)
```